# Why did the Sinclair ZX-Spectrum use a membrane keyboard?

Tags: zx-spectrum, membrane-keyboard

As a kid, I always had problems with the keyboard. Membrane was hard to come by and expensive. I did not have Kempston/Protec. So I had to play on the keyboard.

I was using QAOPMN combination, and shortly it would wear off. Then I had to try to fix it manually, by putting wire and what not. Usually did not work.

In any case, I always wondered why Sir Clive chose the membrane. I suspect it could be to cut down the production cost, but I am not sure.

Comment: Note that most of today's PC keyboards have a hidden membrane under the keys. Seen from that end, Sinclair was pretty modern...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the one hand it was clearly down to cost - being very much cheaper than a conventional keyboard.

However, remember that the Spectrum was the replacement for the ZX81 and ZX80.  These had absolutely no tactile feedback in their capacitive keyboards and so the Spectrum could be marketed as a great leap forward in quality and user experience.  Although that claim was open to debate it did create sales.  A small increase in price gave a large increase in perceived quality and usability.

Also, the membrane keyboard enabled the Spectrum to differentiate itself from competitors that were beginning to appear in the ultra-cheap home computer market from the likes of Oric and Tangerine which had the ZX81-style of capacitive keyboard.

Comment: There was a BBC documentary on Sir Sinclair, but I cant find it anymore.

Comment: @Wexoni:  That was *Micro Men*, http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00n5b92

Comment: It's more of a docu-drama if that, but yes, it's very good :). And yes, the Spctrum's rubber keyboard is much better than the ZX81's membrane one with no tactile feedback at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I can hold with your last sentence mentioning a "capacitive Keyboard" on the ZX81 - There was nothing "capacitive" in that - It was simpla two layers of copper lines with an inbetween shim layer with holes under the contacts.

Comment: It was the same plastic membrane found today on ultra-cheap remote controls. The Spectrum had a slightly better rubber membrane – still cheap but most other computer keyboards aren't better today, having only plastic caps above that membrane.

Comment: There is no "Oric and Tangerine": the Oric was manufactured by Tangerine. It's one machine, total. And even in its original model, before it received a keyboard upgrade, it had a Spectrum-esque membrane: http://de.academic.ru/pictures/dewiki/79/Oric1.jpg

Comment: Nobody ever thought of the Spectrum keyboard as an upgrade. It's competitors were not the ZX80/ZX81 but the BBC Micro and the Commodore 64. The rubber keyboard came in for severe criticism at the time (from owners of the above two machines) although the price of the Spectrum made it a moot point really. People like my brother could, for example, afford the Spectrum but not a Commodore 64 - case closed.

Comment: @JeremyP: nobody said the ZX80/ZX81 were competitors for the Spectrum, they were its direct predecessors from the same company. Hence its keyboard was an upgrade over those predecessors.

Answer (score 14):

As simple as that: because it is the cheapest solution. Mechanical keys, separate circuit boards to hold the switches, etc, add costs to the final product. The ZX Spectrum case is slighly bigger than the circuit board itself, and thick enough to accomodate chips with sockets (there is no room even for a heatsinked socketed ULA).

In addition to manufacturing costs, a "proper" keyboard would surely have caused the case to be bigger, so the polys and cardboard box would have been bigger too, adding more weight (both real weight and volumetric weight, which comes into importance when you have to transport many computers) so the smaller the computer, the smaller the costs associated with storing and delivering them.

It was all about cutting down costs, anyway.

Comment: The Spectrum+, which adds plastic keycaps to get surprisingly close to a modern membrane keyboard, is noticeably chunkier.

Comment: The plus and toast rack keyboards do not age too well sometimes the keys can jam a bit due to sideways freeplay, I have this myself on my own machines.

Answer (score 1):

I had a ZX81 before I had my Spectrum. I am sure I am not alone in being grateful for the huge improvement, at minimal increased cost of the Speccy compared to the 81.

The 81 membrane was very fragile.

So a membrane with rubber keys as movement, and feedback to the user, also added protection to the membrane.

Clive produced hardware that traded off price and reliability, to bring consumer electronics to the masses.

Still, the most common failure of an old spectrum is the membrane. I had to replace mine. They are available on SellMyRetro and elsewhere online, with instructions. Or Mark Fixes Stuff has excellent YouTube videos to show you how.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Please read the [tour]. The only bit of you answer that seems to be a direct answer to the question is the fourth paragraph; the third paragraph is useful but doesn't answer the question and the final paragraph is largely shopping recommendation. Elaborating on the penultimate (fourth) paragraph would improve this answer.